# Applying a dataframe function to raster brick

Tags: r

I’m using musica package, for downscaling climate projections

For example, the musica library has a set of function that are designed to be apply on data frame,
But I want to apply it to my raster stack, and the function needs argument like,

```
dec = decomp(basin_PT$obs_ctrl, period = c('Y5', 'Y1', 'M6', 'M3', 'M1', 'D20'))
```

where obs_ctrl is a data.table with 3 variables: Date ( date object 1980-2005,), pr( vector of rainfall value), and ts( vector of temperature value).
Applying to raster brick
I first create  my date object,

```
cal <- "365_day"
origin <- "1980-01-01"
origin.pcict <- as.PCICt(origin, cal)
seconds.per.day <- 86400
ts.dat.days <- 0:1989
ts.dat.pcict <- origin.pcict + (ts.dat.days * seconds.per.day)
#convert the object to POSIXlt
dtm<-as.POSIXlt(ts.dat.pcict)
```

And then, create the raster brick, 
I have raster brick of 9490 layers (daily gridded rainfaill data),
Here is a raster brick

#####Load required package #########
library(musica)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(raster)
library(PCICt)

```
pr_files= list.files(ipath,pattern='.asc')
rrr<- stack(pr_files)
```

And, overly the decomp function to the raster,

```
rse <- function(dtm, rrr ,period = c('Y5', 'Y1', 'M6', 'M3', 'M1', 'D20')){
  musica::decomp(dtm, pr,period)
  }
```

When applying the function

```
c <- raster::overlay(rrr, dtm, fun = rse)
```

, I received the following error,

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘overlay’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "POSIXlt"’
```

Is there anyway for applying a dataframe function to raster brick?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some simple example data (created with some code, there are numerous examples on-line and in the raster help files, e.g. in `?overlay`) so that your code can run and we can answer your question.

This function seems odd

```
rse <- function(dtm, rrr ,period = c('Y5', 'Y1', 'M6', 'M3', 'M1', 'D20')){
  musica::decomp(dtm, pr,period)
}
```

There is an argument `rrr` that is not used. It should probably be `pr`

You can probably also leave `dtm` out and do

```
rse <- function(pr, period = c('Y5', 'Y1', 'M6', 'M3', 'M1', 'D20')){
  musica::decomp(dtm, pr, period)
}

r <- raster::overlay(rrr, fun = rse)
```

overlay will then find `dtm` in your global environment.